# React, react-select placeholder

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I did some research but couldn't find usefull solution.
Is that possible to keep placeholder always visible? I mean when I pick any option it replaces placeholder spot, but I do not want this, the desired expectation is to keep placeholder visible all the time.

Comment: You mean though some option is selected you want to display placeholder only and not the selected value?

Comment: exactly, i want to keep placeholder displayed not the selected option, sorry if i wrote it  a little bit messy

Comment: Try passing `value={null}` to react-select. But in this case, your `onChange` will always receive single value(not an array).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping placeholder on react-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61895814/keeping-placeholder-on-react-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want users to see what they selected, but still track it in your app, you can make use of `onChange` event to capture what users selected, but still pass `value={null}` to `react-select` so it think that nothing is selected - and it will display the placeholder.